# How to convert data in a Set[Tuple2] into a case class

Tags: scala

One of my methods return a `List[(String,Option[Int])]`. I convert it into a `Set` calling `toSet[(String,Option[Int])]` method of `List`

question 1 - would this give me a `Set[(String,Option[Int])]`?

then I have a case class which can map the data of the `Tuple(String,Option[Int])`

case class `TagCount`

```
case class TagCount (tag:String,count:Int)
```

Is it possible that using the `toSet` method of the `List`, I actually get a `Set[TagCount]` instead of `Set[(String,Option[Int])]

I notice that `toSet` can accept type argument `B >: (String,Option[Int])` but I can't figure out how to make `TagCount >: (String,Option[Int])`

```
def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
def foo(in: List[(String, Option[Int])]): Set[TagCount] =
  in.toSet.collect {
    case (key, Some(c)) => TagCount(key, c)
  }
```

Comment: I'd do collect before toSet but it's insignificant.

Comment: After, can save apply on duplicate

Comment: First of all this is eager modification, also you just could use `.tupled` or `.apply _` instead of patmat.

Comment: You cannot use `apply` directly, as count in input is `Option` not `Int`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming tuple matches the case class field types exactly

```
case class TagCount(tag: String, count: Option[Int])
val s: Set[(String, Option[Int])] = Set("a" -> Some(42), "b" -> Some(11), "c" -> None)
```

we could get `Set[TagCount]` using `tupled` method like so

```
s.map(TagCount.tupled)
```

which outputs

```
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[TagCount] = Set(TagCount(a,Some(42)), TagCount(b,Some(11)), TagCount(c,None))
```